# Setting default value of DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, default-value, datetimepicker

Currently my DateTimePickers are blank, I would like them to have a default setting i.e

```
Today.AddYears(20); & Today.AddDays(5);
```

What I have done at the moment is 'DateTimePicker.Text = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-100).ToString();' As you can probably tell, this isn't working hence why I'm asking the question.

Bit of information :- I need it so that if they arent changed and the button is pressed it uses the default dates. If they are changed, I obviously need to use the changed dates.

Suggestions.

XAML ADDED:

```
<igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor Name="startDateTimePicker"
  Grid.Row="1"
  Grid.Column="1"
  xmlns:igEditors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"
  Height="18"
  Width="100"
  Format="yyyy-MM-dd"
  VerticalAlignment="Top"
  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Answer (score 10):

Setting the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) property should do the trick:

```
DateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-100);
```

And since it's type is `DateTime`, you don't need any `ToString` conversions.

Comment: Thanks for this, however this still isn't showing a value in my DTP. Do I perahps have a problem in my XAML? Would it be an idea to make the Value in to a var and in my XAML put 'Text="var"'  ? Thanks!

Comment: @Vibralux - I assumed winforms, as you did not put any details to the contrary. Can you post the relevant XAML snippet and the code you are using? And provide a link to the DTP you are using.

Comment: Sorry, the application is WPF. Beg your pardon. My XAML for my DTP is as follows: @ Oded, was in the middle of doing that :)

Sorry

Comment: @Vibralux - can you please edit your question and add the data there?

Comment: @ Oded, any chance you could shed a bit of light on your editing techniques for the forums as well?

Comment: @Vibralux - Four spaces before code snippets. Highlight code and click the 0101010 button. For more help, click the orange `?` on the top left of the editor.

Comment: @Oded Thanks - Any answers to my other question :D

Comment: @Vibralux - Sorry, I don't know WPF/XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value property of DateTimePicker Control.

Comment: Will it keep the value in the future? I mean... if I select the previous month from today... will it understand it means today-30 or will it just keep the date I concreted? Uh.